# Android Studio Flutter Hot Reload For Every Change

Tags: flutter, android-studio, hot-reload

When I am writing Flutter app, the android studio perform hot reload for every change I made of the code without pressing the command+S. I want it to trigger hot reload only when I press the command+S, how should I configure it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Settings` and search for `Autosave`. There you can disable or enable autosaving.

[image]